# Very thin white border between cell of a table only on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, html-table, border-layout

This happen only on iPad retina and non retina iOS 5 and 6.

Even if I try to have no border on a table there is a thin white border that appear.

You can see an example of the problem at `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kcexq`.

A iPad or the simulator is needed to view the pb.

Look closely the green tab there is a white border:

[image: look closely the green tab there is a white border]

For the record the same thing happen with display as table-cell.

Comment: Did you tried to add `border-collapse: collapse`?

Comment: Put `<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;' name='viewport' />` in the `<head>`.

Comment: Hi, are there calculations that can result in non-rounded number ( like 12.5px ) ? Also, have you tried resetting border-color-opacity ?

Comment: Sorry, I really tried hard, can't find how to delete those borders. Did you find anything else?

Comment: Anything new with this post ? No solution yet ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890141/css-problem-on-ipad-with-table-border

Comment: also iam facing the same issue. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The thin border that appears seems to be caused by the `display:table-row` and/or `display:table-cell` property.

*Note : it's actually not a white border, it's a kind of `rgba:(0,0,0,alpha)` ; you can see that if you change the background color behind the table.*

By changing `td` style to `display:inline-block;`, or `tr` style to `display:block;`, it gets rid of the left & right border of the cells, but the bottom border stills stands.

In fact, overriding `border-color` with a `rgba(0,0,0,0);` on anything (table, tr, td...) doesn't change anything, neither does `border-collapse:collapse;` (as Morpheus suggested).
Either the computed style doesn't show any border computed, but still, it's here...

**Note: iOS also seems to compute the borders depending on the user's zoom scale (tested on a real iPad).**

Here is the default table style for Safari iOS :

```
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
}

tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}

tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}

td, th {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

I'm still looking for an hidden CSS who could add that alpha border, and will update my answer if I find anything.

Comment: table { ...border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2px; ...}, try focusing on the border spacing.

Comment: @MilchePatern I already tried to override all the default properties, without luck : I've set `border-collapse:collapse;` and `border-spacing:0px;`, no changes...

Comment: Did you overwrite the 'opacity' ?

Comment: @MilchePatern The `opacity` would affect the whole element, not only the border ; I tried `border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` to make the border transparent, without success.

Comment: HEY, rgba(0,0,0,0) means black transparent .. try rgba(0,0,0,1) for the BORDER-COLOR, not the box. Also : background-clip: padding-box; can fix some IE9 behaviors.

Comment: @MilchePatern The OP wants the border to be transparent / inexistant. Anyway, the `border-color` overriding doesn't change anything on iPad. Tried all values of `background-clip` too, no luck.

Comment: transparent != innexistant

Answer (score 1):

This problem has to do with browsers deliberately rendering table cells with a clean 1 pixel border and the behaviour becomes visible most often with a background color. The solution is to wrap/nest the problematic area in its own table and set the background color of the table, rather than the background color of the cells.

The discussion here is very useful on this https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/10/iphone-fail-the-trouble-with-table-borders-and-html-email/

Answer (score 0):

It is because of background.
You should cut image with 1px width and fixed height and put it as a background.

```
td
   {
     background: url('your_url/green_bg.png') repeat-x;
   }
```