# Unwanted border around td on mobile browser type

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have this html code as example to show my issue.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
td {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>White</td>
    <td>White</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see parent element has black background, child element has white, and I can not remove this lines around td in curent example.Same thing with Floted div.

This only on mobile browsers, or chrome mobile  developer view.
Please help)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bppBb.png

To see borders on chrome You have to refresh page after switching to mobile view  If it work on your pc why it would not work on my?
This is full example code.What I am doing wrong?

I am on Windows 10. But any way my HTC shows the same...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style="border-collapse:collapse;border:0px;border-spacing:0;background-color:black;width:300px;height:300px;margin:auto">
  <tr>
      <td style="border:none;background-color:white;padding:0px">White</td>
      <td style="border:none;background-color:white;padding:0px">White</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Even on CssZengarden site this borders is visible on mobile

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVZgR.png

Comment: I think its working fine

Comment: I'm on chrome and working fine with no border

Comment: Try to refresh on mobile view. Thanks for answer

Comment: @SergeySh I am able to replicate the issue, and its weird, well can't you use border instead of backgroundcolor?

Comment: Thing is, I dont need borders at all. This is only example. In real I have big page with many div inside each others and large color selection. It looks all fine on pc, but once you go to mobile it all have this "borders" if parent element have other background...  Thanks for answer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6305878/118153, has a partial solution if you don't zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I could recrete the issue and i recommend using the css3 display table instead of using actual tables.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="cell">TEXT HERE</div>
  <div class="cell">TEXT HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested it in chrome 45. With the mobile/ responsive testing tool where i could recreate the table borders. They do not show with the display: table.

Comment: @Perijn@ you did not set background color... Parent black, child white, than you will see

Comment: @SergeySh i edited the code to include black parent white child. (That sounds so wrong)

Comment: Well, now I see if I run your code shippet in here on mobile it looks ok, but when I copy code to my file localy and run on mobile IT SHOWS borders.Looks like StackOverflow  use some sort of CSS reset and this what I am looking for. I have try some public CSS reset , but no success...

Comment: But even in here your code shippet shows border on chrome with mobile version viewer. Maybe only my chrome? version 45.0.2454

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `border: 0 none !important;` for `table`, `tr`, `th`, and `td`. I am suggesting the `!important` only to make sure your borders don't come from any CSS by third parties which you might have included.

If that fails, you can still try to apply `border-color: transparent;` or `border-color: #your-background-color;`, or `border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);` as a workaround.

As a last resort, you can also try setting

```
border-style: hidden;
```

Comment: I don't think it is a border as such. It is more likely a background of parent element. Because if I change backgoround color for parent element, those borders change color too...

Comment: yes exactly. It's not a border....

changing "background-color:black" property to "background-color:white" in <table> is solving the issue.

Comment: Yes, I got this , but in my document I need background in black for example.  This is only example. And I have tested some websites and lots of them have this borders , thay not visible like black on white, but still... Seem to me, developers don't care much about it, or it is not posable to solve. One think I try and it worksis if you add 2px solid border to child element in same color as background of parent this will make look much nicer. but still visible to seelittle margin

Comment: how about adding background-color:white to <tr>? The border isn't completely hidden but still it's damn too light now and also not visible in many websites....

here: <tr style="background-color:white">

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same problem and found a solution.

I was working with 12% black 1px borders and this solved it:

```
>td[colspan] { border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.06) !important; }
```

Mysteriously using the half visibility made the double-border matching. Using just `border-color` or `border-top-color` + val as well does not solve this.